# Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object on the same domain

Tags: javascript

the script on `somemydom.com/iframe_loader` loads iframe `somemydom.com/iframe/to/load` with a form. I need to submit it and I do the following thing(domains are the same):

```
doc.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
```

but I get error

```
Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object
```

its even denied on the same server? Is that possible to fix?

EDIT:
full code:

```
<?php
    echo "<iframe src=\"https://somemydom.com/iframe/to/load\" id='supiframe' target=\"_parent\" height=\"100%\" width=\"100%\"></iframe>";
    echo "
            <script type='text/javascript'>
    //        console.log(document.getElementById('theForm').action)
        document.getElementById('supiframe').onload= function() {
            var ifrm = document.getElementById('supiframe');
            // using reference to iframe (ifrm) obtained above
    var win = ifrm.contentWindow; // reference to iframe's window
    // reference to document in iframe
    var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;

    doc.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].target = '_parent';
    doc.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
    }

    //        </script>
        ";
```

Comment: Is it possible, that you've reloaded the page in the iframe after you've defined `doc`?

Comment: @Teemu seems no, check my edit

Comment: Why is everything wrapped in PHP? Wouldn't it be easier to just use the tags normally?

Comment: Try to load the iframe source by a relative URL, maybe you've loaded the main page with a differet domain. Protocols, domains and ports must literally match, ex. `localhost` is not the same domain as `127.0.0.1`, although they're addressing the same resource.

Comment: @Aplet123 page I load is iocube encoded and belongs to one platform, I can't read the code or access it but I need to submit the form. Php script is a middle part to allow submit that generated form page

Comment: @Teemu replaced url to '/iframe/to/load'  same thing (